# Get max value from record set with common columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Per the below record set, I have three columns and need to return the max CaseId value for every set of PersonIds.

```
ID    PersonId  CaseId
66    30        410
1681  30        3508
226   31        958
856   31        2213
1023  31        2400
```

For example, I would like to return a recordset such as:

```
ID    PersonId  CaseId
1681  30        3508
1023  31        2400
```

As you can see, I'm always returning the max CaseId for all sets of PersonIds.

I've tried the following but it doesn't always return the max record:

```
WITH latestRecord AS
 (
  SELECT  CaseId, PersonId, ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY ID ASC) AS RN
  FROM    Employee
  )
  SELECT  Max(RN),CaseId, PersonId
  FROM    latestRecord
  GROUP BY RN,CaseId, PersonId
  --WHERE   RN > 1
  ORDER BY CaseId
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a subquery to find max CaseId value for each set of PersonIds.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Employee t
  JOIN (
        SELECT PersonId, MAX(CaseId) AS CaseId
        FROM dbo.Employee
        GROUP BY PersonId
        ) t2 ON t.PersonId = t2.PersonId AND t.CaseId = t2.CaseId
```

For improving performance use this indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX x ON dbo.Employee(PersonId, CaseId) INCLUDE(ID)
```

[image]

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3d335/1)

Answer (score 3):

You had it almost right:

```
WITH latestRecord
AS
(
    SELECT  CaseId, 
            PersonId, 
            ID,
            RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId ORDER BY CaseId DESC) 
    FROM    Employee
)
SELECT  CaseId, 
        PersonId, 
        ID
FROM    latestRecord
WHERE   RN = 1
ORDER BY CaseId
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Very strangely, this works in SQLFiddle but not my RDBMS...hmmm...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```
SELECT EMP.ID, DRVDTBL.PERSONID, DRVDTBL.CaseId FROM 
(select  max(PERSONID) as PERSONID, CaseId from Employee
group by CaseId) AS DRVDTBL
INNER JOIN Employee EMP ON DRVDTBL.PERSONID=EMP.PERSONID
```

Comment: it's the other way round, OP needs `max(CaseId)` for each `PersonID`